# Unable to turn bluetooth on, Ubuntu 18.04, Asus Vivobook S400CA

Tags: 18.04, bluetooth

When I try to turn bluetooth on the button turns orange but nothing else happens. It keeps saying Bluetooth turned off.

```
rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0032] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: AzureWave AR9485 Wireless Network Adapter [1a3b:2126]
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
    Kernel modules: ath9k
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros AR8161 Gigabit Ethernet [1969:1091] (rev 10)

dmesg | grep Bluetooth
[    2.282077] usb 1-1.1: Product: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
[    5.003871] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.003890] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.003893] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.003896] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.003902] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    8.293624] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    8.293625] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    8.293629] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   10.336040] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1003 tx timeout
[   12.352040] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1001 tx timeout
[   14.364130] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x1009 tx timeout
[   32.317225] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   32.317231] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   32.317237] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11

lsusb
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 03eb:8807 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1bcf:2883 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 13d3:3402 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb`

Comment: edited the lsusb

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem with an Asus Eee and Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

The solution that worked for me was to restart the driver with:

```
rmmod btusb
modprobe btusb
```

Found this from bug report: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=894542

Comment: This also solved the same bluetooth problem on a Asus ROG desktop, thanks!